# Angular 2 event inside innerHTML node

Tags: angular

```
<tr *ngFor="#t of DBSERVER | firebaseevent:'child_added'">
   <td [innerHTML]="t.Source"></td>
</tr>
```

t.Source is for example

```
<a (click)="myComponentFunction('test')">test</a>
```

with innerHTML the click event is not fired. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not directly supported.
You would need to add a component instead of an HTML string.
Another way is direct DOM access where you query the HTML and add and event handler imperatively but that seems quite cumbersome.

Comment: How can I add a component instead of an HTML string? Any example? Thanks!